# Roulette Program - Adding up the cash

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.5

I have a project for a class to create a Roulette wheel minigame and I'm having issues. I set the initial cash to $100 and let the user play roulette. After they've given their wager and it's time to tally up the cash for the next round, I'm having issues setting the new cash value. Basically, I need to add the winnings/losings to the value of cash so that it's accurately updated for the next round. I know that declaring cash as a global variable is wrong, but we haven't learned the proper way to do it and haven't had time to check it out for myself. Anyways, the issue is near the bottom. Thank you for any help! -

```
import math
import random

def main():
    global cash

    print('Welcome to Roulette! We\'ll start you with $100')

    cash = 100 #set to 100 for intitial

    menu()

def menu():

    print('Place your bet! ',cash,'bucks!', '''
=======================================
1. Bet on Red (pays 1:1)
2. Bet on Black (pays 1:1)
3. First 12 (pays 2:1)
4. Middle 12 (pays 2:1)
5. Last 12 (pays 2:1)
6. Choose any number (pays 35:1)
7. Cash out
Please enter your choice: ''')
    menuChoice = int(input())
    #Add validation!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    if cash > 0 and menuChoice != 7: #Determine if quit or broke
        if menuChoice == 6:
            number = int(input('Please choose a number from 0-36!')) #Get their specific number
            while number < 0 or number > 36: #Validation
                number = int(input('Please enter a number from 0-36'))


        wager = int(input('How much would you like to bet? '))
        #Add validation!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        print('Press any key to spin the wheel! ')
        input()
        print(menuChoice, wager)
##
##        ball = random.randint(0,36)
        ball = 19 #set to 19 for testing. REMOVE AND RESET BALL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        if ball == 0:
            color = ('green')
        elif ball % 2 == 0:
            color = ('black')
        else:
            color = ('red')

        print('Your ball was',ball, 'and landed on the color',color)

        #Determine if winner
        if menuChoice == 1 and color == 'red':
            winner = True
            odds = 1

        elif menuChoice == 2 and color == 'black':
            winner = True
            odds = 2

        elif menuChoice == 3 and ball >= 1 and ball <= 12 :
            winner = True
            odds = 2

        elif menuChoice == 4 and ball >= 13 and ball  <= 24:
            winner = True
            odds = 2

        elif menuChoice == 5 and ball >= 25 and ball  <= 36:
            winner = True
            odds = 2

        elif menuChoice == 6 and ball == number:
            winner = True
            odds = 35

        else:
            winner = False
            odds = 0

            #End determine if winner

        if odds == 0:
            pass
        else:
            amount = wager * odds   #Get amount won/lost
            print(amount)

        if winner == True:
            cash += amount #<~~~~~~~~~~~~~Problem Area
            print('Congratulations! You won', wager,'dollars!')
            print('Your total is now :',cash,'dollars.')
        else:
            cash -= wager
            print('Sorry! You lost',wager,'dollars. Better luck next time!')
            print('Your total is now :',cash,'dollars.')

        input('Press a key to go back to the menu!')

        print('====================================================================')

        #New round
        menu()




    else:
        print('Thank you for playing! ')
        exit

main()
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: You need `global cash` inside _every_ function that does an assignment to `cash`. BTW, you have some typos, eg under `elif menuChoice == 2 and color == 'black'`, the odds should be 1, not 2. And `exit` should be `exit()`; even better: import `sys` and make it `sys.exit()`

Comment: BTW, to get the looping behaviour it would be better to use a `while` loop in `menu` rather than calling `menu` inside itself. That wastes memory and will crash with a recursion error in about 1000 rounds.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll be sure to use that information. I originally had it set to while but I was getting some repeated strings in places they shouldn't have been. I'll change it back to while and try to figure those issues out, as well. Thanks so much for the information.

-edit- 
You were right. I added global cash to menu() and it's now working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own python class, with the methods you already have. Than you can declare `cash` a class variable, with the parameter [`self`](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/). With `self.cash`  you can than access the variable in every method. If that does not help please comment this answer with your issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, we haven't gotten that far in lectures. We're still pretty early in the class, and it's an intro class. I'll see if I can't find a youtube video explaining it though. Thanks.

Comment: Thats why I added the link to the self parameter. It is nicely explained there.

Comment: But checkout the Comment from PM 2Ring, that might work too.